Setting up Conversion API
I would like to setup a conversion API. Is there a step by step demo I can watch?
I tried following the steps in the suggested setup articles and it seems like I am doing something wrong with the setup.
Is it possible to watch a step by step setup video or arrange to have a consultant help guide me through the setup steps?
